# How to get Notified when Method is Called on Object that does not Implement Observable?

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to somehow know when the adapter of a ListView instance changes.

I was thinking of adding an observer to the listView object, but it does not implement the Observable interface.

```
ListView listView;
      listView.addObserver(...); // method does not exist!
```

Is there any other way I can know when the adapter of a list view changes? e.g. the setAdapter() method is called... ?

--- UPDATE ---

Here's an code example:

```
final ListAdapter firstAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] {"AAA"},
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
);
final ListAdapter secondAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] {"AAA"},
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
);

setListAdapter(firstAdapter);

(new Timer()).schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        setListAdapter(secondAdapter);
      }
    };
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(r);
  }
}, 1000);
```

My question is: How can the `firstAdapter` know when it is detached from being the listView's actual adapter (because `secondAdapter` replaces it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Adapter gets notified when it's deregistered from the ListView, so I am using this:

```
@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
  super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);

  Log.d("Adapter just got unregistered from the listView!");
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You can set an observer on the adapter.

[registerDataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver(android.database.DataSetObserver))

Comment: No, just tested, neither the onChanged nor the onInvalidated method gets called when registering an DataSetObserver when the adapter changes. I will add another example to clarify ;)

Comment: I don't know of anything that would do that besides creating a class that extends BaseAdapter and then having a method `notifyAdapter` when you want to set the second adapter. So you would call `firstAdapter.notifyAdapter()` and then `setListAdapter(secondAdapter)`. Again not sure if that's what you are looking for.